# Pass Value from Jquery Variable to window.open

Tags: jquery

I have following Jquery code that alerts a value of an HTML field in this variable `$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val());`

My problem is i want to pass this value to variable val like this

```
window.open("http://abc.com/crop/test.php?val="+$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val()),"_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");
```

but its not passing the value.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

      <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").live("change", function () {
        if ($(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val() == "") {
            return;
        }
        // your ajax submit
        alert("submit value of the file input field=" + $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val());


        $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
    });
    });//]]>  

    window.open("http://abc.com/crop/test.php?val="+$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val()),"_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="attachmentsUpload" action="/UploadHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="file" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your html, especialy this input. PS. Don't use live(), use on() instead.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra close parenth in the `window.open` statement. Try changing `val())` to `val()`?

Comment: @ckpepper02 HTML added

Comment: Made my comment an answer if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand it:

```
$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
```

So then:

`$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val()` returns string empty

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an extra close parenth in the `window.open` statement. 
Try changing `val())` to `val()`

**So:**

```
window.open("http://abc.com/crop/test.php?val="+$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val()+","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");
```